# Laravel 5 eloquent recursive programming

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have then next 2 tables

```
/* systems */
id    sys_name
 1    Debtors
 2    Creditors
 3    Cashbook

/* menus */
id    system_id    parent_id   menu_desc
1         1            0       Maintenance
2         1            1       Maintain Debtors
3         1            2       Debtor Addresses
4         1            1       Maintain Clerks
5         3            0       Bank Reconciliation
```

I have 2 Eloquent models

```
/* System */
public function menus(){ 
   return this->hasMany(Menu::class,'system_id','id')->where('menus.parent_id','=',0);
}
public function submenus(){ 
   return this->hasMany(Menu::class,'system_id','id')->where('menus.parent_id','=','menus.id');
}

/* Menu */
public function system(){
   return $this->belongsTo(System::class,'system_id','id');
}
public function parent(){
   return $this->hasOne(Menu::class,'id','parent_id');
}
public function children(){ 
   return $this->hasMany(Menu::class,'parent_id','id');
}
```

I want to achieve the following in blade.php:

```
@foreach($systems as $system)
   ....... 
   @foreach($menus as $menu)
      .......
      @foreach($submenus as $submenu)
          ........
       @endforeach
    @endforeach
 @endforeach

with the following output: (I am using bootstrap for indentation)

Debtors
   Maintenance
      Maintain Debtors
         Debtor Addresses
      Maintain Clerks
Creditors
Cashbook
   Bank Reconciliation
```

MenuController

```
$systems = System::with('menus','submenus')->get();
```

but it doesn't work. 
There are no submenu records.
I think the problem is 'menus.id' in function submenus() but dont know how to solve it.

Please help as I have battled more than 3 days to build a menu treeview.

Thanking you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do what you want is to use a nested relation.

Instead of trying to build a `->submenus()` relation, instead just use the already-existing `->children()` relation on your `Menu` class:

```
Route::get('systems', function() {
    $systems = System::with('menus.children')->get();
    return view('systems')->with('systems', $systems);
});
```

Then your `systems.blade.php` template can just be something like

```
<pre>
Systems
@foreach($systems as $system)
    {{$system->sys_name}} Menus
    @foreach($system->menus as $menu)
        {{$menu->menu_desc}} Submenus
        @foreach($menu->children as $submenu)
            {{$submenu->menu_desc}}
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
@endforeach
</pre>
```

As an additional advantage to that method, you can get all menus with subsubsubmenus with `System::with('menus.children.children.children')->get()`, and so on.

Comment: Thank you Joshua @irfani. Is there any way to found out how deep the levels are that I have to cater for in the blade.php with @foreach?

Comment: You'll probably want to use a partial which recursively `@include`s itself (see [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/laravel-blade-recursive-partials/) for an example).

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the submenus() function on the menu model file, since your tree structure is
`system
   menu
      submenu`

or you can just change the with syntax to

`$systems = System::with('menus','menus.children')->get();`

and change the submenu foreach with $menu.children

```
@foreach($menu->children as $submenu)
```